# Why does my material's vector displacement not look the same in render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, vector

This is the material with vector displacement I created...    (In viewport mode)

[image]

This is how it turned out in rendered mode

[image]

Why???

I tried changing the material settings to enable "displacement" or "displacement only" but nothing's changed.

I tried setting my Cycles mode to "experimental" but nothing's also changed.

I know this has already been asked here in Blender Stack exchange but those were of different versions. I am using 2.93 and I can't find anything that helps.

Also, here's the node setup if there is something wrong here. (BTW I made this node with the help of [CGcookie's Vector displacement tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekaQPkEdudw&t=503s))

[image]

Man, this is just something straightforward but it's causing me alot of grief...

Comment: I suspect you have a Subdivision Surface modifier with different settings for ‘Render’ than for preview. Check the modifiers and/or the scene “Simplify” settings.

Comment: Yes! Problem SOLVED. Thanks Man.. who knew such simple stuff like this could be so obscure...

Comment: Great. Yes, there are some conmon things are just waiting to trip you up if you don’t know what to look for. For some - like this - i think it would be best if the ‘render’ one was never allowed to be lower than ‘preview’ without warning the user - since it’s something that shouldn’t generally be the case.

Answer (score 4):

This can be a result of a Subdivision Surface modifier with different settings for ‘Render’ than for preview or “Simplify” settings restricting the maximum subdivisions. Check your Modifiers for Render subdivisions being less than Preview subdivisions.